# BeagleBone - 2 programs running in parallel

Tags: terminal, putty, beagleboneblack

simply put I got this situation:

**Q 1)** I have 2 programs (one in C++, one in JavaScript) and I need to run them both at the same time - > I hope to get the answer in form of console command 
- is e.g.

```
./main & ./main
```

rigt way to do that? The trouble is, I cant close both programs with "CTRL + C" (one is running in the backgroud and cant be even closed with "CTRL + Z")

**Q 2)** How to communicate between 2 programs running in parallel ? E.G. Is it possible to "put" the JavaScript program into 1 thread under the C++ program?

- I am considering to write&read from file (synchronization based on real time), as it is sufficient for my to send/receive 1 byte / minute 
  (hey, terrible idea, but as long as it works, it is not stupid)

**PS**

BeagleBone Black with Angstrom

terminal program Putty (multi-Putty is not working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While developing, just use 2 consoles.  When done with development, I assume your 2 apps will run as services.  As far as communication, an external file will work, but something like dbus or port communication would probably be better.